# View monetdb table content

Tags: monetdb

How can I view the content of a MONETDB tables ?
In WAMP for example I just type localhost in the browser and there i can see 
All the tables and databases with their content .
But I'm unable to do so in MONETDB , Or to be more accurate I don't know how .
Plus the documentation doesn't provide info on the matter .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've installed it on a machine running linux, you need to first set up a farm using the server daemon (monetdbd), then create a database on said farm using monetdb. You can then set up tables and run SQL queries using the mclient that you can fire up using

mclient -u monetdb databasename

There is a step by step guide to setting up a basic database here: http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/UserGuide/Tutorial

For windows, you'd have to start the monetdb server and then use the monetdb sql client. This is also detailed in the windows tutorial:

http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/UserGuide/Tutorial/Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can view the MONETDB Tables by using the following command:

\d

The above command list all the tables in a schema you have logged into.

If you want to check content of a particular table use the below command:

\d TABLE_NAME